# How to deploy an applet JAR locally on a Windows system that will override the server version of the JAR?

Tags: java, applet, classpath, bigbluebutton

I have a situation where the version of an applet provided by a service provider is outdated, and I am wondering if I can somehow install the updated version of the applet's JAR locally (somehow in the classpath I'm guessing) and have the Java client load that instead of the one at the path specified by the `<applet>` tag.

If you want specifics, the product is BigBlueButton and the problem I'm trying to solve is with the v0.81 of the client applet [not working with newer versions of java](https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/issues/detail?id=1748). Our service provider has not updated their JAR for some reason, and until/unless they do we'll be forced to install an old version of Java on all our 6000 systems.

So, since I have the ability to push files to our systems, I'm wondering if I can put the developer-provided updated JAR files somewhere where it will be loaded by the browser instead of the one provided by the server. I can also potentially prevent the browser from downloading the one from the server (e.g. via proxy tricks) if that helps. Is this possible? If so it would be a neat workaround that would prevent us having to deploy multiple Java runtimes in our environment.

Comment: The easiest way to handle this is to contact your service provider and have them update the Jar.

Comment: @Kayaman Agreed! It's a problem of timing. I'm sure they will eventually, but we have to start using this widely soon, likely before they do (they're shutting down our current alternative). So...now what?

Comment: `I'm sure they will eventually`. That doesn't sound very convincing. Contact the provider and ask them to update the version, or if they have other alternatives.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, I'm working that process now. And...well....the issue is, this is "Gub'mint". So speed is not likely their strong suit.

Comment: Well then, as far as I know, there's no way to create a local override of an applet (that would be a security issue, not to mention other things).

Comment: @Kayaman "that would be a security issue, not to mention other things" Agreed also. I figured since I have access to the local disk and classpath, there might be a "white-hat" something I could do like cache-cramming, but understand there may not be. Just thought I'd throw it out there to see if anyone had any ideas.